# Oracle SQL Developer Query to return the count of 2 values from same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count the number of two types of transactions in a column and to return a value of 0 if there are none.  The table is Transaction, the columns I want returned are the account number and a column for the count each of the two transactions listed.  here's what I have, but it doesn't run:

```
SELECT 
ACCTNBR, 
COUNT(CASE when RTXNTYPCD='XDEP'then 1 else 0) AS Deposits,
COUNT(CASE when RTXNTYPCD='PWTH'then 1 else 0) AS Debits

FROM  
TRANSACTION 

WHERE 
((POSTDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('05-01-2014','MM-DD-YYYY')) AND TO_DATE('05-31-2014','MM-DD-YYYY')) 

and ACCTNBR in ( 406,   1206,   1347,   4556,   6668,   9845)

GROUP BY 
ACCTNBR
```

Comment: what error are u getting? is it maybe related to adding a space before each of your `THEN` keywords? Or maybe adding an `END` to the `CASE`? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `count` function counts any value that isn't `null`. Since both `0` and `1` are not `null`, both your `count`s will return the total number of rows in your table. Instead, you should use `sum`:

```
SELECT 
 ACCTNBR, 
 SUM(CASE when RTXNTYPCD='XDEP' then 1 else 0 END) AS Deposits,
 SUM(CASE when RTXNTYPCD='PWTH' then 1 else 0 END) AS Debits
FROM  
 TRANSACTION 
WHERE 
 ((POSTDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('05-01-2014','MM-DD-YYYY')) AND 
                     TO_DATE('05-31-2014','MM-DD-YYYY')) 
   and ACCTNBR in ( 406,   1206,   1347,   4556,   6668,   9845)
GROUP BY 
 ACCTNBR
```

Comment: Thanks - but after correcting the SYN to SUM, I still get an error:ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 12